# Is there a way to alias columns for reference in subqueries?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a SQL statement in PostgreSQL that takes the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (b + 1) IN (SELECT b FROM db WHERE a = 7)
```

This query returns each record whose `b` value, incremented by 1, is in the set of all `b` values of the records matching `a = 7`. However, I'm looking for a way to write this in the form of an `EXISTS` statement, since that may be more optimal. Something of the form

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db WHERE a = 7 and b = b* + 1)
```

where `b*` somehow references the `b` attribute not inside the subquery, but outside it. Is there a way to write the first query without `IN` and with `EXISTS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table alias for **both** occurrences of the table and then prefix every column with the corresponding table alias to make the column references unambiguous.

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from the_table t2
              where t2.a = 7 
                and t2.b = t1.b + 1);
```

Note that you probably want something like `and t2.primary_key <> t1.primary_key` in the sub-select as well.